# How to determine the relations among the coefficients of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Let $m,n,s,t$ be non-negative integers such that $n^2+s^2=2+ms+nt$. We know that all roots of $x^3  - (m + s)x^2  + (ms - n^2  - 2)x + 2s = 0$ and $x^3  - (n + t)x^2  + (nt - s^2  - 2)x + 2n = 0$ are real, and  the largest positive roots (they must have) of these two polynomials are integers. Can we determine more precise relations among  $m,n,s,t$?

Comment: Try Gröbner bases.

Comment: If we write $y$ and $z$ for the largest roots of these two polynomials, then we can view this as a system of equations $n^2+s^2 =2+ms+nt$, $y^3- (m+s) y^2 + (ms-n^2-2)y+2s=0$, $y^3- (n+t) x^2 + (nt-s^2-2)y + 2n=0$. This is a system of Diophantine equations of total degree $8$ in $6$ variables, so it might not have very many solutions, and one could try number-theoretic methods, which would start by studying the complex geometry of the solution set.

Comment: The remaining conditions, that the two roots of $\frac{ x^3- (m+s) x^2 + (ms-n^2-2)x+2s=0}{x-y}$ are real and $\leq y$, and the analogous ones for the other polynomial, are inequalities and thus less useful.